# Tool to check compatiblity with Matlab versions?

Tags: matlab, compatibility

I have several scripts (m Files) and our customers have different Matlab versions. Is there a tool to check for compatiblity of each script with certain Matlab versions?

Comment: +1 great question, would love it if MathWorks developed such a tool. Perhaps you should make a [feature request](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/01/14/making-a-feature-request/)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not. I think it would be a nightmare to maintain such a tool by the flood of incompatible changes they introduce with each Matlab version. It would already help, if they'd put the version number when they introduced/changed/deprecated/removed certain features into the documentation, but they don't care (I tried that as a feature request via their support, but they didn't bother. Maybe if more people requested that... )

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to do what you want with the `checkcode` function. Alternatively, you can use functions such as `version` and `verLessThan` to write your scripts and functions such that they check which version they are being run on and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 3):

**For MATLAB R2017b and newer ONLY:**

Yes, we do have a tool to create a [codeCompatibilityReport](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/codecompatibilityreport.html#mw_6593a034-66c0-429d-9e69-cf7e7cdb82af) for the current working folder and subfolders. This feature was introduced in MATLAB R2017b. The code compatibility report opens in the MATLAB Web Browser. After you upgrade to a newer version of MATLAB, you can use this report to identify potential compatibility issues in your existing code.

Navigate to the directory hosting your M files that you wish to run the code compatibility report for, within MATLAB. Then, execute the following command:

```
>> codeCompatibilityReport
```

The code compatibility report contains information to help you upgrade your code to a new version of MATLAB. It contains these sections.

**Incompatibility and Syntax Errors** — Table with details about syntax errors and incompatibility considerations in the analyzed code. For example, "Using ~ to ignore a value is not permitted in this context or 'wavfinfo' has been removed. Use 'AUDIOINFO' instead."

**Warnings and Other Recommendations** — Table with details about warnings and other opportunities to improve your code. For example, "Programmatic use of DISPLAY is not recommended. Use DISP or FPRINTF instead."

**Checks Performed** — Details the checks performed on the specified code.

**Files** — List of files that MATLAB analyzed for code compatibility.

**Here is a link to the MATLAB Answers Post with more information:**
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/364764-is-there-a-tool-to-check-for-compatibility-between-different-matlab-versions

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Matlab that you are migrating to, there is a feature called the Upgrade Advisor which can check this sort of thing (it's very similar to the Simulink Model Advisor).

Comment: Can you describe how to use it - I'm on 2011b and can't find the function.

Comment: My appologies, I seem to have had a bit of a senior moment here. The Upgrade Advisor is only available in newest versions of Matlab (although the Model Advisor will still do much of the checking that I think you're after). @Mark 's solution below should do exactly what you're after.

Comment: @BigA: Its still not clear to me, are you talking about a pre-release beta version of MATLAB (R2012b)?

Comment: What you mean is probably the hints that mlint spits out like "Don't use that feature anymore", "This function will be deprecated in the next release" and so on, but that doesn't really help you if you want to stay backwards compatible with different matlab versions.